# Can DoxBox ( or FreeOTFE Encfs Truecrypt ) prompt and mount an encrypted file volume or encrypted disk partition before Windows boots to its GUI?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption, luks

I would like to Encrypt a secondary drive (NOT the OS/boot drive) and have it mounted and drive letter mapped etc, before Windows 7 gui boots up. This is because I will have mapped some user data onto the encrypted secondary drive so I need it to actually exist and working when trying to login to windows.

I'm primarily interested in DoxBox or equivalent windows encryption system that's compatible with dm-crypt / Luks etc. But if that's not possible with DoxBox I'm willing to consider Encfs or even Truecrypt and derivatives. Ideally something with decent performance like that of Truecrypt or Luks.

I'd also be interested in any performance tests comparing Bitlocker with Luks / dm-crypt. (Seems its been documented Bitlocker is faster than the others.)

(DoxBox started off as a fork of FreeOTFE seems..)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can open LUKS-encrypted drives created on the Linux side with DoxBox in Windows. But if you create OTFE-encrypted volumes or files with DoxBox, your only hope of opening them in Linux is to install DoxBox in Linux via WINE.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's acceptable for me. But my main question is if on windows, I can have the encrypted drive "mounted" before the Windows graphical system boots up, like to get a 'prompt' during bootup to type in my key/pass to mount the encrypted drive before logging in to Windows.